# How to get Project Wise Summary numbers from one Google Sheet to another?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

I am trying to create a Project accounting Google sheet.

In one sheet I have all the expenses, revenues for the projects. (see below)

[image]

and the other sheet will have list of projects with Summary of Revenue, Expense and Profit (see below)

[image]

Is there a formula in Google sheet which can help me fill the Summary sheet with project-wise data?

Credit = Revenue

Debit = Expense

Any help would be highly appreciated?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the **SUMPORUDCT** function:

*Revenue*:  `=SUMPRODUCT(($C$2:$C$7="Credit")*($E$2:$E$7=B10),$D$2:$D$7)`

*Expense*:  `=SUMPRODUCT(($C$2:$C$7="Debit")*($E$2:$E$7=B10),$D$2:$D$7)`

[image]

[image]